# How can I assign an index to each of these input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

Right so the question maybe doesn't illustrate what I'm trying to say but here's what I'm trying to achieve. I have got 6 text boxes on a page each of which contains a number between 0 and 500 (there is no limit but I'm not expecting the number to be higher than this). This number is dependent on a calculation elsewhere, but is irrelevant for this question so I've left it out. Anyway, what I'm trying to do is;

Run through a loop and assign a new text box `scoreone, scoretwo` etc in the code below an index between 1 and 10 based on the size of the values in `indexone, indextwo` etc.

So for example if `indexone` contains 15, the textbox `scoreone` will be populated with 0. Now this works fine, but only for one textbox, as I have six, I'm not sure how to do this for all of them (i.e. one after the other). I'm using JavaScript and jQuery...

HTML:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="20" id="indexone" />
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0" id="scoreone" /><br>


<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="60" id="indextwo" />
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0" id="scoretwo" /><br>


<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="100" id="indexthree"/>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0" id="scorethree" /><br>


<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="160" id="indexfour"/>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0" id="scorefoure" /><br>

<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="180" id="indexfive"/>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0" id="scorefive" /><br>


<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="210" id="indexsix"/>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0" id="scoresix" /><br>
```

JS:

```
var indexArray = [indexone, indextwo, indexthree, indexfour, indexfive, indexsix];

for (var i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) {
    if ((indexArray[i] >= 0) && (indexArray[i] < 25)) {
        scoreone = parseInt(1);
        $('#scoreone').val(scoreone);
    }
    else if ((indexArray[i] >= 25) && (indexArray[i] < 50)) {
        scoreone = parseInt(2);
        $('#scoreone').val(scoreone);
    }
    else if ((indexArray[i] >= 50) && (indexArray[i] < 75)) {
        scoreone = parseInt(3);
        $('#scoreone').val(scoreone);
    }
    else if ((indexArray[i] >= 75) && (indexArray[i] < 100)) {
        scoreone = parseInt(4);
        $('#scoreone').val(scoreone);
    }
    else if ((indexArray[i] >= 100) && (indexArray[i] < 125)) {
        scoreone = parseInt(5);
        $('#scoreone').val(scoreone);
    }
    else if ((indexArray[i] >= 125) && (indexArray[i] < 150)) {
        scoreone = parseInt(6);
        $('#scoreone').val(scoreone);
    }
    else if ((indexArray[i] >= 150) && (indexArray[i] < 175)) {
        scoreone = parseInt(7);
        $('#scoreone').val(scoreone);
    }
    else if ((indexArray[i] >= 175) && (indexArray[i] < 200)) {
        scoreone = parseInt(8);
        $('#scoreone').val(scoreone);
    }
    else if ((indexArray[i] >= 200) && (indexArray[i] <= 225)) {
        scoreone = parseInt(9);
        $('#scoreone').val(scoreone);
    }
    else if (indexArray[i] > 225) {
        scoreone = parseInt(10);
        $('#scoreone').val(scoreone);
    }

}
```

I've put what I'm trying to do in a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wthFv/3/) too...

Comment: Why not change what the id's are.  So instead of `scoreone` use `score1` and make the name by appending `score` + `i` where `i` is the loop iterator

Comment: what is the point of `parseInt(6)`? 6 is already an int.

Comment: @MarcB you're right, that's just redundant! I will remove...

Comment: Do you realize the >= checks in all of the ifs are redundant. Of course it is greater or it would have not gotten past the previous steps.

Comment: @epascarello again, you're right. Wtf am I doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this working example witch changed words for ints:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wthFv/7/)

Comment: Excellent. This worked with a bit of tweaking (I didn't need to bind it to an `onClick`. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Just use classes and loop through

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="20" class="index" />
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0" class="score" /><br>


<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="60" class="index" />
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0" class="score" /><br>


<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="100" class="index"/>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0" class="score" /><br>


<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="160" class="index"/>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0" class="score" /><br>

<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="180" class="index"/>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0" class="score" /><br>


<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="210" class="index"/>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0" class="score" /><br>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
//That whole if/else if statement reduced to a calculation
function getValue(val){
    var number = (Math.round(val/100*4)/4)*100/25;
    if (number>10) {
        number = 10;
    }        
    return number;
}

//Find all of the indexes and scores, returned in document order
var indexes = $(".index");
var scores = $(".score");

//loop through indexes and set the value on the corresponding score
indexes.each(function(ind) {
    var index = jQuery(this);
    var score = scores.eq(ind);
    var value = getValue(index.val());
    score.val(value);
});
```

[Running example](http://jsfiddle.net/faGQG/2/)

Comment: and jquery will magically know what the OP wants to modify only the .score elements that follow immediately after the .index being considered... how?

Comment: Thanks but the problem is, the values for indexone, indextwo etc are always different as they are dependent on other calculations...

Comment: @MarcB the elements are returned in document order so as long as the result is in the same order as the index, there is no problem.

Comment: @Kiz, your comment gives me no more information to go off on.

Comment: @epascarello, sorry what I was trying to say was the values that I'm using to calculate the indexes for, so for example `indexone, indextwo` etc are actually calculated fields (i.e. the values in these boxes can change). Hope this makes sense

Comment: The selected answer is almost the same exact answer as this, the each is a for loop. :)

Comment: @epascarello ah yes. Sorry, I perhaps should have accepted this as you answered first! Thanks for your help though, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/wthFv/5/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this simplifies:

Update the Ids for the fields to use index number as suffix as `score1`, `score2`.. and `index1`, `index2`...

Then write a compact java function as below:

```
 for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    $('#score'+i).val(Math.ceil($('#index'+i).val()/25));
  }
```

If you don't want to change the ids then, I think below should work.

```
var indexArray = [indexone, indextwo, indexthree, indexfour, indexfive, indexsix];
var scoreArray = [scoreone, scoretwo, scorethree, scorefour, scorefive, scoresix];

 for (var i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) {
    $('#'+scoreArray[i]).val(Math.ceil($('#'+indexArray[i]).val()/25));
  }
```